# drupal block variable_set not saving select value

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am trying to created a block that saves a value from a select box.  However, after reload, variable_get does not return the saved value... so variable_set seams not to be working.

What am I doing wrong here?  (Drupal 6)

```
function get_courses(){
   global $user;     
    $my_items_sql = 'SELECT course_node.uid, ';
                     //get the course nid
                     $my_items_sql .='course_node.nid as course_nid, ';
                     //get the course title
                     $my_items_sql .='course_node.title as course_title ';
                     $my_items_sql .=' from node as course_node where course_node.type="course" and course_node.uid = "'.$user->uid.'"';
                     $my_items_sql .=' order by course_node.nid; ';
                     $my_items_data= db_query($my_items_sql);

                     $my_courses = array();
                     while ($row = db_fetch_array($my_items_data)) {

                            //$course_node = node_load($row["course_nid"]);
                            $my_courses[$row["course_nid"]]=$row["course_title"];
                     }
                     //$variables['courses']=$my_courses;
                     //drupal_add_js(array('courses'=>$my_courses), "setting");

         return $my_courses;
}
function front_page_block($op='list',$delta = 0, $edit = array()) {

    $course_options = array();
    $courses = get_courses();
    $tmp = $courses;
    $first_course = $tmp;
    reset($first_course );
    $first_course_nid = key($first_course);

    $first_course_nid = key($first_course);
    switch($op){
        case 'list':
            $blocks[0]['info']= t('Course Data Loader');
            $blocks[0]['cache']= BLOCK_NO_CACHE;
            return $blocks;
        case 'configure':
            $form['course_to_display'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#description' => t('Display flashcards from which deck on the front page?'),
            '#options' => $courses,
            '#default_value'=>variable_get('front_page_deck_to_load', $first_course_nid)
            );
            return $form;
        case 'save': 
            variable_set('front_page_deck_to_load', 
                $edit['front_page_deck_to_load']);

            break;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

At first check, what value is set for **$edit['front_page_deck_to_load']**, before call the

**variable_set('front_page_deck_to_load', $edit['front_page_deck_to_load']);** function.

If the value of **$edit['front_page_deck_to_load']** is set properly, then variable_set is working.

Now the problem is, the **'#default_value'** of **$form['course_to_display']** is not set properly. Please modify the **get_courses()** function as follows and try again:

```
function get_courses(){
   global $user;     
    $my_items_sql = 'SELECT course_node.uid, ';
                     //get the course nid
                     $my_items_sql .='course_node.nid as course_nid, ';
                     //get the course title
                     $my_items_sql .='course_node.title as course_title ';
                     $my_items_sql .=' from node as course_node where course_node.type="course" and course_node.uid = "'.$user->uid.'"';
                     $my_items_sql .=' order by course_node.nid; ';
                     $my_items_data= db_query($my_items_sql);

                     $my_courses = array();
                     while ($row = db_fetch_array($my_items_data)) {

                            //$course_node = node_load($row["course_nid"]);
                            $my_courses[$row["course_title"]]=$row["course_title"];
                     }
                     //$variables['courses']=$my_courses;
                     //drupal_add_js(array('courses'=>$my_courses), "setting");

         return $my_courses;
}
```

FYI: Please follow the **Comments #1** at http://drupal.org/node/240783